# SQL Report Builder: get another value from a parameter?

Tags: sql, reporting-services, reportbuilder

I have a report parameter called "Month". It comes from a dataset that include a few other fields including "FinYearStart".

My report has several datasets. On uses @Month as parameter and thus gets the value of the Month parameter selected by the user.

One of the other datasets uses a date range. The end date is @Month, but I want the start date to be the value of the FinYearStart according to the @Month selected by the user.

So my question is, can the said dataset have it start date parameter filled with something like this:

```
Parameters!Month.Fields.NameOfAnotherFieldInTheParametersDataset
```

just like how the end date value is simply `Parameters!Month.Value` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given that your financial year start is in the same dataset that you get your `@Month` parameter from, you should just be able to extract it from there using a [Lookup](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee210531.aspx):

```
=Lookup(Parameters!Month.Value, Fields!Month.Value, Fields!FinYearStart.Value, "MonthsDataset")
```

You can then set this to the expression for a hidden parameter that you can use in your dataset query.